Reading json file in pyspark with nested structure array of array of dictionaries
I am trying to read the following JSON data which is inside a data.json file:
[
    [
        {
            "haha": 5
        },
        {
            "haha": 6
        }

    ],
    [
        {
            "haha": 7
        },
        {
            "haha": 8
        }

    ]
]

I tried the following PySpark code:

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

# Initialize SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Schema Inference Example") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).json("data.json")
df.show()

but this outputs the following:
+----+
|haha|
+----+
|NULL|
+----+

I suspect it has to do with the array-of-arrays of dictionaries structure. Is there no way to load a JSON file with this structure in PySpark? My file will have more fields than this example and I won't be able to provide a schema, I was hoping PySpark could do its magic and infer the schema and give me the dataframe.

Could you please provide the required output as well? I assume it will be one column "haha" with 4 rows with values 5, 6, 7, and 8?

Yes, that is correct @VikasSharma

Updated Answer:
As per your comment you want to utilise the distributed nature of Spark - then instead of just Pandas - you can use Pandas API on Spark to get the best of both worlds.
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    json_string = f.read()

flattened_ls = [item for sublist in json.loads(json_string) for item in sublist]
df = ps.DataFrame(flattened_ls).to_spark()
df.show()

Output:
+----+
|haha|
+----+
|   5|
|   6|
|   7|
|   8|
+----+

According to the official Spark docs, pandas-on-Spark DataFrame and Spark DataFrame are virtually interchangeable.

Original Answer:
I think Pandas is much better at dealing with JSON stuff than PySpark. You can utilise it as follows for your use case:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
import json

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

pd_df = pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in data for item in sublist])
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
df.show()

Output:
+----+
|haha|
+----+
|   5|
|   6|
|   7|
|   8|
+----+


But using pandas would defeat the purpose of using the distributed nature of Spark. Is there a way of doing it without relying on Pandas?

@Lua I have updated the answer as per your requirement - let me know if this works.

Also, I just validated that the JSON you shared in your question is corrupt as per Spark. For more information, please see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html So, there won't be a trivial way to handle it. You can validate it here: https://jsonlines.org/validator/ I think using Pandas API on Spark might be your best bet here for now - unless you are ready to change the input JSON structure.
